# Unexpected error for recursive collatz implementation

Tags: c, collatz

**EDIT: When I upload the code to the automatic testing platform the program doesn't crash there - it returns the correct result, but takes too long (exceeds 5 seconds)... wtf...**

For university I have to implement a function that returns the number of steps taken from the input to reach 1, by following the collatz conjecture. The conjecture is very simple - given any integer number:

**1.** If it is even - divide it by two (n/2)

**2.** If it is odd - times it by 3 and add one (n*3+1)

The conjecture is that all numbers will eventually reach 1. We don't have to prove or check  this, we just need to return the steps taken for a given number.

We have done this problem before, but this time we must check much larger numbers (they specify to use long instead of int) **AND** use recursion. They have given us skeleton code, and asked us to implement only the function - so all of my code is contained inside

*int lengthCollatz(long n) { //mycode }*

The skeleton code in the main collects two input values - a and b, where a < b <100000000. It checks how many steps it takes for each number between a and b, following the collatz sequence, to reach 1, and then returns the number with the highest amount of steps taken.

The function I added seems to work perfectly fine, but at larger values (when input 2 is in the millions) it seems to crash for no reason and gives no error. I've tried changing everything to unsigned longs and even long longs to see if something is overflowing - in that case the program just gets stuck... I don't understand what's wrong, please help me diagnose the error. P.S. How can I improve the speed of these calculations? We have a limit of 5 seconds.

All of my code is inside the lengthCollatz function (and the length global variable just above it) Can you identify the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX64 9223372036854775807L /* 2ˆ63 -1 */

int length = 0;

int lengthCollatz(long n) {
    length++;
    //if not 1
    if(n!=1){
        //if odd
        if(n&1) {
            lengthCollatz(n=n*3+1);
        }
        //if even
        else {
            lengthCollatz(n/=2);
        }

    }
    //if reached n = 1
    else {
        //return amount of steps taken
        int returnLength  = length;
        length = 0;
        return returnLength;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int n, a, b, len=-1;

scanf ("%d %d", &a, &b);

while (a <= b) {

    int l = lengthCollatz(a);
        if (l > len) {
            n = a;
            len = l;
        }
        a++;
}
printf("%d\n", n);
return 0;
}
```

Updated function:

```html
int lengthCollatz(long n) {
        if(n==1){
            //return depthRecursion;
        }
        else {
            if(n&1) {
                n=n*3+1;
            }
            else {
                n/=2;
            }
            return lengthCollatz(n);
        }
}
```

Comment: try running your code through a debugger. The only reason why it could crash would be stack overflow due to recursion too deep. sometimes it exits without messages unless you use the debugger.

Comment: Your recursive calls don't need `n=n*3 + 1` and `n /= 2` either. Just use `n*3 + 1` and `n/2`

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to use recursion?  That's just asking for trouble when you don't have a good handle on the needed recursion depth.

Comment: In any case, using a file scope variable to help you track the recursion depth is unnecessary, and I'm reasonably confident that it's not what your instructor expects you to do.  I don't think that's related to your problem, but I recommend considering how you might perform the computation without relying on any file-scope variables.

Comment: I do hope that `long` is 64 bits on your system, although I wonder if you use `unsigned` values throughout, perhaps 32 bits will be enough.

Comment: I don't understand how to correctly use the debugger - it returned a SIGSEGV error which confirms your and mine suspicions about overflow. There is a tab with data about the call stack, but I'm unsure how to interpret it to deal with the problem. Oops! the 'n=n*3 + 1' was an oversight while editing code here in the site, I've already corrected that. And yeah, they explicitly demand recursion. Thanks, John, I'll try not get rid of the file-scope variable.

Comment: Ugh, I can't figure out how to not use the file-scope variable without implementing a new argument into the function, which I'm not allowed to do... Any hints? Also, still no solution for the main problem found... helppp

Comment: Your recursive calls are ignoring the function's return value. And not all control paths return a value anyway. Do you have compiler warnings enabled?

Comment: We know almost nothing about collatz conjecture, and its flight time can be very high; it may happens that your stack overflows... Using recursion for this is just a nonsense.

Comment: Compiling the code generates `warning C4715: 'lengthCollatz' : not all control paths return a value`... The two calls `lengthCollatz(n*3+1)` and `lengthCollatz(n/2)` doesn't return value.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I can't agree more, but the highest number I'd have to check is 10^8 for this excercise... I also just found this phrase in the excercise description **You may assume that the type long
will not overflow for the given interval (this has been checked for you).**
So the program overflowing is their intended solution??? WTF

Comment: @Aldo There are multiple types of overflow to consider. The exercise tells you that the *type* `long` will not overflow during the execution, but if your compiler does not manage to eliminate the recursion, you *will* see *stack overflow* (rather appropriate, don't you think?)

Comment: @EOF I did not know that! So I'm overflowing the call stack by too many recursions... How can I remedy this? I'm also 100% percent sure they don't want us to handle/solve things like this... is it possible the problem lies outside of the code?

Comment: @Aldo You can avoid stack overflow by either rewriting the code to use iteration rather than recursion, or, if you *must* use recursion, rely on the compiler to do this rewriting. Now, C does not mandate that the compiler rewrite code to eliminate tail-recursion, but good compilers do. However, you need to help the compiler along. You will have to remove the global variable and make sure the recursive call is at the very end of the function (like `return lengthCollatz(...);` inside `lengthCollatz()` itself).

Comment: @EOF Ah so it's my global variable at fault! Thank you for the in depth explanation, my only problem then is - how do I keep track of the depth of recursion (the count of steps), without introducing a new argument to the function (not allowed) AND without using a global variable? I just can't figure out another way...

Comment: I've edited my thread with the new function at the bottom, but how to count the depth still baffles me :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's one alternative version which does not segfault for the input range given by OP:

```
int collatz(unsigned long n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else if (n & 1) 
        return 1 + collatz(n * 3 + 1);
    else
        return 1 + collatz(n >> 1);
}
```

AFAICT, it works OK, but it's very slow. 29 seconds on my mediocre PC. An optimized version runs two seconds faster by not calling itself when the result can be precomputed, but that version borders on manual loop unrolling. FWIW:

```
int collatz(unsigned long n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;

    if (n & 1) 
        return 2 + collatz((n * 3 + 1) >> 1);

    // Is n dividable by 16?
    if (n & 0xF == 0)
        return 4 + collatz(n >> 4);

    // Is n dividable by 8?
    if (n & 0x7 == 0)
        return 3 + collatz(n >> 3);

    // Is n dividable by 4?
    if (n & 0x3 == 0)
        return 2 + collatz(n >> 2);

    return 1 + collatz(n >> 1);
}
```

There are of course other ways to solve this, but to finish in five seconds? Please post the solution if you find one.

Comment: Hey, I just tried running the first function and the program still crashes at 1m+ ranges... Although the logic you programmed is very impressive and interesting! I don't understand it very well. My logic was to use recursion until the number reaches 1 and then to print the depth of recursion. You don't track the depth of recursion anywhere, but I suppose it's the +1 that somehow does this. Can you explain how/why this works? Thanks for the reply

Comment: Glad you liked it :) Were you able to meet the five second requirement?